# How to map array to type with nested mapping in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I want to map an array to type to other.

I tried this:

```js
const a = {
  label: "A",
  actions: {
    a() {},
    b() {},
  },
} as const;

const b = {
  label: "B",
  actions: {
    c() {},
    d() {},
  },
} as const;

type I = [typeof a, typeof b];

/*
Map to:

{
  A: {
    a: () => void;
    b: () => void;
  },
  B: {
    c: () => void;
    d: () => void;
  },
}

*/
type R = {
  readonly label: string;
  readonly actions: any;
};

type M<T extends R> = {
  [K in T["label"]]: T["actions"];
};

type T = {
  [K in keyof I as I[K] extends R ? I[K]["label"] : never]: I[K] extends R
    ? M<I[K]>
    : never;
};
```

I want to each field has its dedicated type, say `A : {a, b}` and `B : {c, d}` but I only get a result in unions like:

```js
type T = {
    A: M<{
        readonly label: "A";
        readonly actions: {
            readonly a: () => void;
            readonly b: () => void;
        };
    } | {
        readonly label: "B";
        readonly actions: {
            readonly c: () => void;
            readonly d: () => void;
        };
    }>;
    B: M<...>;
}
```

[Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gKBjANnARgUywC4YAiAQVIBoN5goBLcCE9TTOACgEpUBfGuxi4e-QTAFo%208CDFCQoAbjRp50YUlS0cBYmQBC1WnHpNIrWpmCiUkoQBMbdiTWlxZapSqgBPAA74MACSmgDavgEgAGbwVDAR%20NHCALrKaAD0AFRoALJwfvEgRCpsMOQWQnAkoogAfDAAbiAM9spCuNW8dY3NrbTO%20hXswJ1I9U0tbez2o90TfZiSfCqZ6WgJMABKmqUATvhw9uBYPth4hCTQuwxgAOZT%204fHpyaMzCRwYD7KfGkbOQAeAAqMHwAA8oPgwPZZJt6shSqEANIwG4wIGhUg6QikZLJEgY0ivMwQXE-P7%20QIghG0ZGosAwADW%20B8SRC7mCyOSoIhUJhWxgAH5OUjkpjsVhcTASGB8A18Lt8SLueDIdDYZYhTBAUEubVNTK5QryWggA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) to get the union of elements of `I`:

```
type Item = I[0 | 1]
```

This is terrible, right? Fortunately, you can replace `0 | 1` with `number` which will return every element of the array/tuple type:

```
// type Item = {
//     readonly label: "A";
//     readonly actions: {
//         readonly a: () => void;
//         readonly b: () => void;
//     };
// } | {
//     readonly label: "B";
//     readonly actions: {
//         readonly c: () => void;
//         readonly d: () => void;
//     };
// }
type Item = I[number]
```

Now, using [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) and [key-remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) we can get the expected result:

```
// type Result = {
//     B: {
//         readonly c: () => void;
//         readonly d: () => void;
//     };
//     A: {
//         readonly a: () => void;
//         readonly b: () => void;
//     };
// }
type Result = {
  [K in I[number] as K['label']]: K['actions'];
};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gKBjANnARgUywC4YByAQVIBoN5goBLcCE9TTOACgEpUBfGuxi4e-QTAFo+8CDFCQoAbjRp50YUlS0cBYmQBC1WnHpNIrWpmCiUkoQBMbdiTWlxZapSqgBPAA74MACSmgDavgEgAGbwVDAR+NHCALrKaAD06fH+gQBK+BAArliwyOiZQjD6FhWV7ABO+HD24Fg+ciSiiAB8MABuIAz2yrV1MI3Nre32nbw9-YPDGVlCfCMr7OQ1G3UTLWBt8LNIvQND62OYe1PCx-NnS6OYa8sSaAkw+UUlmmwwoQBpGAMMDBUJgQoAWwI9WSMhgANCpB0hFIyWSJERpBMjGYaOULyAA)

Comment: It works. Could you please explain how does `K in I[number]` work? It doesn't look like a common pattern.

Comment: It is indeed a very common pattern. We are mapping through a union of elements of the tuple. It's pretty much the same with the `keyof` which returns a union of keys, which wasn't relevant in our case. Look at the type of `Item` which is exactly a union of the `I` elements

Comment: By the way, is there any document about difference between `0 | 1` and `number`?

Comment: in the indexed access docs, there is a place where the `[number]` is used. The exact difference is that `0 | 1` will only return the union of the first two elements, whereas the `number` will return all of them. The first version may be used only if you need the first two, but if you need to get all of them you would need to always come and extend the union `0 | 1 | 2 | ...`